# awk - remove the content of a text file

Tags: file, text, awk

I have two text files with different numbers:

File a:

```
115491
106835
121256
123166
75028
```

File b:

```
135991
95770
143987
125900
125899
```

every file does only contain a number once.

File a contains ALL posible numbers, file b contains just a few. I would like to have a file c which contains only the numbers, that are not already included in file b.

I would like to have as a result, that if I merge file b and c, I have file a (the order is not important).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the example you gave, this grep line may help:

```
grep -vFwf fileb filea > filec
```

if you love doing it with awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]++;next}!a[$0]' fileb filea > filec
```

Comment: @kent if each number only appears once in each file you don't need the `next`.

Answer (score 0):

Hacky awk way

```
awk '++a[$0]<ARGIND' fileb filea >filec
```